# JQuery/Ajax & Spring Rest Multi-part form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, rest

I am quite new to JQuery and I was trying to do some asynchronous multipart form uploading. The form consist of few data fields and a file type. I have set up the server side code (Spring) like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Upload multipleSave(MultipartHttpServletRequest request)
    {
        Upload upload = new Upload();
        Iterator<String> iterator = request.getFileNames();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            MultipartFile file = request.getFile(iterator.next());

            try
            {
                System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("File Length: {0}", Arrays.toString(file.getBytes())));
                System.out.println("File Type: " + file.getContentType());
                upload.setContent(file.getBytes());
                upload.setDocId(id++);
                upload.setError(null);
                upload.setName(file.getName());
                upload.setSize(file.getSize());
                fileList.put(upload.getDocId().toString(), upload);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error occurred: " + e);
                upload.setError("500: Something went wrong!");
            }
        }

        return upload;
    }
```

and client side code like this:

```
  function processFileUpload()
  {
    console.log("fileupload clicked");
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", files[0]);
    $.ajax({dataType: 'json',
      url: "/SpringJqueryFileUpload/upload",
      data: formData,
      type: "POST",
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function (result) {
        alert('success' + JSON.stringify(result));
      },
      error: function (result) {
        alert('error' + JSON.stringify(result));
      }
    });
  }
```

When I do submit, the server responds with this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.upload.model.Upload
```

I am wondering with error. Could I be missing something here??

Comment: How do you want the server to respond? Can you show the `Upload` class and also do you have Jackson in your project?

Comment: I want the server to respond with the Upload object in JSON format as seen in the Controller's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try changing your annotation to:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

And make sure you have Jackson (which Spring uses for JSON serialization) properly on your path. Also, make sure your `Upload` class is serializable, e.g. is not `private` or anything like that. If it is just a normal Java bean type class it should be fine.

Lastly, if that doesn't work you can turn on Spring debug logs with something like:

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.web=ALL
```

in your log4j.properties file.

Comment: I appreciate your time. Here is what I get now after writing the produces to  Application_JSON. [TRACE] [http-apr-8080-exec-94 07:47:17] (ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:invokeAndHandle:132) Error handling return value [type=com.upload.model.Upload]

Comment: Method [public com.upload.model.Upload com.upload.controller.UploadController.multipleSave(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest)]

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: To solve HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException I added a missing Jackson file and it is working now. Thanks for your help.